# Using a column alias with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am receiving an error " Unknown column 'YahrzeitName' in 'on clause'" when trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT 
concat(yahrzeit.firstName, ' ', yahrzeit.middleName, ' ', yahrzeit.lastName) 
AS 'YahrzeitName', 

concat(yahrzeit.gregorianYear, '-', yahrzeit.gregorianMonthNum, '-', yahrzeit.gregorianDay) 
AS Date,

tbldecedent.Name

FROM yahrzeit INNER JOIN tbldecedent 
ON YahrzeitName = tbldecedent.Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use column alias in `join` statement, replace alias with full expression:

```
SELECT 
    concat(yahrzeit.firstName, ' ', yahrzeit.middleName, ' ', yahrzeit.lastName) AS `YahrzeitName`,
    concat(yahrzeit.gregorianYear, '-', yahrzeit.gregorianMonthNum, '-', yahrzeit.gregorianDay) AS `Date`,
    tbldecedent.Name
FROM yahrzeit 
INNER JOIN tbldecedent
ON concat(yahrzeit.firstName, ' ', yahrzeit.middleName, ' ', yahrzeit.lastName) = tbldecedent.Name
```